# Is apollo-vue package compatible to be used in nuxt-ts?

Tags: nuxt.js, apollo, apollo-server

I followed official documentation(https://github.com/nuxt-community/apollo-module) of apollo-vue package but I couldn't get $apollo variable ready to use in my project. Printing it on console gives me apollo object but I still get error in terminal that $apollo or this.$apollo does not exits.

Comment: Even the example in official docs doesn't run successfully out of the box! command "npm run dev" gives error.